# ¿Como puedo "enviar" un archivo .txt a una aplicación .exe que lo procesa con python?

Tags: python

Sobre el escritorio de Windows, puedo seleccionar el .txt y arrastrarlo sobre un .exe que hace determinada tarea, y funciona correctamente.

La idea es realizar el mismo proceso desde python3 vía comandos.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano,

Saludos.

Toni

Comment: bienvenido, por favor revisa [ask] la idea de la comunidad es apoyar pero se requiere tengas un avance y muestres lo que has tratado y hasta donde te has quedado; por favor revisa el [tour]

Comment: No entiendo si quieres que un .py se ejecute al arrastrar y soltar sobre el intérprete python (creo que esto ocurre ya por defecto sin que tengas que hacer nada), o si lo que quieres es desde python lanzar un ejecutable que tome un archivo como parámetro, en cuyo caso puedes usar `os.system()` pasandole la cadena `"ejecutable archivo_a_procesar"`. Es posible que tengas que especificar las rutas absolutas al ejecutable y al archivo a procesar. En ese caso cuidado con las barras \ que usa Windows, pues debes escribirlas dobles en las cadenas python "\\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui hacerlo con:

```
From subprocess import call
Call ([“el.exe”,”el.txt”])
```